# not array reference with perl XML::Simple code

Tags: xml, perl

I've been testing `XML::Simple` with some xml file outputs and have noticed where in one of my xml files if I have more than (1) file path, my script will work (**2.xml**)

If I have only (1) file path (**1.xml**) then I will get this message: `Not an ARRAY reference at ./tst-simple.pl line 28`

My questions are why won't the code work on (1) file path? I am using ForceArray=>1. How do I handle this?

**1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing time="2011-10-04T02:33:44+0000" recursive="no" path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" exclude="" filter=".*" version="0.20.202.1.1101050227">
    <directory path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" modified="2011-10-04T02:32:11+0000" accesstime="1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000" permission="drwx------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
    <file path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731/myfilename-00" modified="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" size="123456789" app="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
</listing>
```

**2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing time="2011-10-04T02:33:44+0000" recursive="no" path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" exclude="" filter=".*" version="0.20.202.1.1101050227">
    <directory path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731" modified="2011-10-04T02:32:11+0000" accesstime="1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000" permission="drwx------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
    <file path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731/myfilename-00" modified="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" size="123456789" app="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
    <file path="/storage/foobar/test/queues/20110731/myfilename-01" modified="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" size="123456789" app="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="unix_act" group="foobar"/>
</listing>
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = $ARGV [0]; 
my $data = XMLin($xml); 

for my $xs ($xml) {
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 0);
    my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 1);
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => [ qw ( path ) ]);
    print Dumper ($data);
}

foreach my $file( @{ $data->{file} } )
{
    my( $dir, $fname );
    if( $file->{path} =~ /^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/ )
    {
        $dir = $1;
        $fname = $2;
    }
    else 
    {
        $dir = "";
        $fname = $file->{path};
    }
    print "This is the DIRECTORY: $dir\n"; 
    print "This is the FILE:      $fname\n";
    print "This is the FILE SIZE: $file->{size}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different variables named `$data`. One was created using `ForceArray => 1`, but you're using the one that was created without using `ForceArray => 1`.

Replace

```
my $data = XMLin($xml); 

for my $xs ($xml) {
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 0);
    my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 1);
    #my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => [ qw ( path ) ]);
    print Dumper ($data);
}
```

with

```
my $data = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => 1);
print(Dumper($data));
```