# cannot print out variable called from perl sub routine

Tags: perl

I want to convert my foreach loop to a sub routine `sub mybits`. I'm sure I am not calling this properly or for that matter setting it up as a sub.

What I want to do is return a value from the sub routine which is any one of three variables which i tested foreach part and am able to get data.

Got this mesg. I am using strict, warnings: `Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call`

How do I call this sub routine to get either of my variables `($dir, $fname, $fsize)`?

**Code:**

```
my $out;
mybits (my $dir)=$out;
print mybits($dir);
print "This is mybits: $out\n";


sub mybits 
{
    foreach my $file( @{ $data->{file} } )
    {
        #my( $dir, $fname );
        my( $dir, $fname, $fsize );
        if( $file->{path} =~ /^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/ )
        {
            $dir = $1;
            $fname = $2;
            $fsize = $file->{size};
        }
        else
        {
            $dir = "";
            $fname = $file->{path};
        }
        #print "This is the DIRECTORY: $dir\n";
        #print "This is the FILE:      $fname\n";
        #print "This is the FILE SIZE: $fsize\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you `use strict` and `use warnings`?  Further, it doesn't appear as though `mybits` is returning anything.  Also, why would you assign  the value of `mybits($dir)` to an uninitialized scalar and then expect `print mybits($dir)` to produce anything?

Comment: yes, i edited my question with the mesg. thanks.

Comment: The error message means that you're trying to assign the return value of a subroutine to some other scalar.  Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: For that matter, `mybits` doesn't even take any arguments, since you're not doing anything with `@_` inside of `mybits`.

Comment: ok, i hope i made my question clear. I have a routine and would like to make it a sub() call to it to extract any one of the variables described.

Comment: Also, you're calling `$file` as an element of the array `@{$data->{file}}`, but then you mention `$file->{path}`, which would indicate that `$file` is a hash reference....  Is `$data->{file}` an array reference of hash references?  What is the structure of `$data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to get at any of `$dir`, `$fname`, or `$fsize` in your subroutine as written, since their scope is limited to your subroutine (specifically to the `foreach` loop within your subroutine).  You'll have to have your subroutine return these values.  However, since these are used over and over again in a loop, you'll probably want to return all possible values.  Perhaps something like:

```
sub mybits 
{
    my $return_dirs=[];
    my $return_fnames=[];
    my $return_fsizes=[];
    foreach my $file( @{ $data->{file} } )
    {
        #my( $dir, $fname );
        my( $dir, $fname, $fsize );
        if( $file->{path} =~ /^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/ )
        {
            $dir = $1;
            $fname = $2;
            $fsize = $file->{size};
        }
        else
        {
            $dir = "";
            $fname = $file->{path};
        }
        #Put the relevant data into the array references that we'll return later.
        push @$return_dirs,$dir;
        push @$return_fnames,$fname;
        push @$return_fsizes,$fsize;
    }

return [$return_dirs,$return_fnames,$return_fsizes];
}

my $values=mybits();

foreach(@$values)
{
  print join(",",@$_) . "\n";
}
```

**Note:**  All of this assumes that the rest of the code in `mybits` actually works correctly...given that the OP only provided some of the code (eg we have no idea what `$data` is), I can't guarantee that this is the case.

Comment: thank for your reply. I am building off of my last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656290/not-array-reference-with-perl-xmlsimple-code. This shows $data.

Comment: @cjd143SD - You're welcome.  So, have you tried altering your subroutine as described above?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it. So if the values `($return_dirs, $return_fnames, $retrun_fsizes)` are stored in `my $values`, is it possible to print out any one of them? Let's say I want to print only `$return_dirs`, how would i do that? thanks.

Comment: Each of `$return_dirs`,`$return_fnames`, and `$return_fsizes` are **array references**, and `$values` is a reference to the array whose elements are `$return_dirs`, `$return_fnames`, and `$retrun_fsizes` (respectively).  So, since `$return_dirs` is the first element, you can just do the following:  `print join(",",@{$values->[0]}) . "\n"`.  But before you do any of this, I'd really recommend reading through some introductory Perl books (eg Beginning Perl) or at least `perldoc perlref` so that you understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
mybits (my $dir)=$out;
```

tries to assign `$out` to the value returned by your subroutine. This is not possible, it's not a valid *lvalue* hence the error. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: It's even worse, since `mybits` doesn't have any arguments...  My best guess is that the OP trying to get at the values of `$dir` defined inside of `mybits` (which, of course, is impossible, since the scope of `$dir` is inside of `mybits`), but I can't tell for certain.